# How to change live streaming latency with AWS?

Tags: cdn, live-streaming, aws-serverless

I build a live streaming app with:

[AWS serverless video streaming](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/solutions/serverless-video-streaming/) and  [speedylive](https://www.speedylive.live/)

Recently, many users have reported that the live broadcast is very stuck and delayed.

User feedback sometimes shows that the live broadcast delay is as high as 10 seconds, and the freeze is also very serious.
Should I use CND, or some other solution.

Comment: What streaming protocol(s) are you using?  When you say it's "stuck", what specifically do you mean?  If you're using a segmented protocol such as HLS or DASH, this latency is typical.  If you really need low latency (and are willing to pay for the expense and deal with the quality tradeoffs), WebRTC is what you must use.

Comment: @Brad
I use SDK which uses RTMP.
Some users are in Southeast Asia. Is the reason for my app latency due to AWS's own network problem?

Comment: RTMP doesn't work in browsers, so what are you using for the output?